# How i can open the browser prompt to save password with a input made with Web Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component

I have one `input password` maded with Web Components and i'm having some problems with the prompt "Save password" opened by the browser after submit the form.

Seems that the because the shadow root, the browser can't access this DOM element and identify that should show this prompt.

I created this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-webcomponents-2019-ry7t8x?file=index.js) with a reproduction.

In the first input, maded with Web Component, the prompt can't identify that have to save this credentials. In the second input, with the same properties as the first, the browser prompt to save the credentials. 
I tried to put a `hidden input` with `name="password"` and `type="password"` and before the `submit`, i replaced the value of my `hidden input` with the value filled in my webcomponent, but seems that the prompt only open when user click and type.

I'm looking if there's some way to open this prompt with web components. I'm using chrome.

This is my React component that have the form:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import './web-components/InputText';

const TestApp = () => {
  const submited = e => {
    console.log('submitted form!');
  };
  return (
    <div>
      Hello Webcomponents 
      <form onSubmit={e => submited(e)}>
        <custom-input />
        <input type="password" />
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<TestApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is my web component input:

```
const templateHTML = `
  <label for='custom-input'></label>
  <div id='content'>
    <input name="password" id='custom-input' type='password'/>
  </div>
`;

class InputText extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    this.update();
    this._label = this._shadowRoot.querySelector('label');
    this._input = this._shadowRoot.querySelector('#custom-input');
    this._content = this._shadowRoot.querySelector('#content');
    this._input.addEventListener('keyup', this.inputChangeHandler.bind(this));
  }

  update() {
    this._shadowRoot.innerHTML = templateHTML;
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (
      !this.hasAttribute(name) ||
      (this.hasAttribute(name) && oldValue !== newValue)
    ) {
      this[name] = newValue;
    }
    this.update();
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['value', 'label', 'type', 'name'];
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.currentCount = this.getAttribute('count') || 0;
    this.update();
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
    this._input.removeEventListener(
      'keyup',
      this.inputChangeHandler.bind(this)
    );
    this.update();
  }

  inputChangeHandler(event) {
    this.value = event.target.value;
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('inputChange'));
    this.update();
  }

  get name() {
    return this._input.name;
  }

  set name(value) {
    this._input.setAttribute('name', value);
  }

  get value() {
    return this._input.value;
  }

  set value(value) {
    this._input.value = value;
  }

}

window.customElements.define('custom-input', InputText);
```

Comment: I don't see anything special here that warrants shadowDOM. Maybe you do not need shadowDOM encapsulation functionality, and you can do **without shadowDOM**

Comment: hello @Danny'365CSI'Engelman thanks for the reply. Do you have any example of how i can create a web component without shadowDOM? i tried something like:  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true)) but this dont render anything. thanks anyway :)

Comment: Do not use ``attachShadow()``, and then everything ``this.shadowRoot`` becomes ``this``

Comment: thanks @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, i tried to remove the shadowRoot, but nothing is being rendered and i receive: Maximum call stack size exceeded, this is what i tried: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-webcomponents-2019-selynb?file=web-components/InputText.js

Comment: React doesn't support Web Components out of the box. Create a vanilla javascript Web Component first. Once it does what you want, make it work in React (you need to create a wrapper React component for every Web Component because React is in control of the DOM and Events) .... or ditch React